# Sincèrement et sincerely

Tags: correspondance, salutations

Il me semble que la formule "sincèrement" n'est pas aussi répandue que la contrepartie anglaise "sincerely". Ai-je raison ? Si oui, pourquoi ? Sinon, dans quels cas peut-on l'utiliser ?

Je viens de recevoir un courriel tout à fait formel par le service d'une préfecture suite à une demande de ma part et le courriel termine par "cordialement". Est-ce normal dans un tel registre ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La formule *Cordialement* est en effet la plus répandue lorsqu'on écrit un mail "professionnel" ou "formel", ou *Cdlt*/*Cdt* si la personne nous est familière (les professeurs de mon école l'utilisent quand ils nous écrivent, par exemple).

*Sincèrement* est cependant tout aussi acceptable, mais on le trouve rarement aujourd'hui, *Cordialement* étant très pratique et passe-partout.

*Sincèrement* sera peut-être à préférer quand on posera une question à quelqu'un, que l'on demandera quelque chose ou qu'on remerciera quelqu'un, pour exprimer sa gratitude, car on finit souvent ce genre de mail par *Merci*.

Answer (score 2):

Le courrier électronique a changé les règles épistolaires. Il y a seulement une trentaine d'années, lorsqu'on écrivait couramment des lettres manuscrites, on pouvait terminer une lettre un peu formelle par "je vous prie de croire à l'expression de mes sentiments les meilleurs", sauf si, de sexe masculin vous écriviez à une femme, sans essayer de la courtiser, il valait mieux, selon l'étiquette en cours à cette époque terminer par "je vous prie de croire à l'expression de ma considération distinguée", certes assez loin d'une invite.

Tout ceci n'a plus cours, mais le "sincèrement" est un anglicisme en fait employé couramment depuis toujours en anglais avec le "Sincerely yours" ou "Truly yours". Le "cordialement" ou "bien cordialement" est tout à fait français et passe partout et pour ma part, je l'utilise assez couramment. Il n'y a rien d'incongru dans le fait que la préfecture vous écrive en terminant de la sorte. Si vous souhaitez informer votre correspondant de votre reconnaissance sincère pour un service rendu, vous pouvez terminer par "avec mes remerciements les plus sincères" ou mieux "avec mes plus sincères remerciements", cette dernière formule mettant en valeur la sincérité (une denrée rare) devant la gratitude.